# Can I install Steam Workshop mods on a game purchased outside of Steam?

Tags: steam

I have bought games outside of Steam, for example *Fable 3*, but I want to install some mods for it from the Steam Workshop. I would prefer to use Steam Workshop to install mods, as I don't trust my abilities to install them manually. Plus it's a lot easier to manage from the Steam Workshop.

What I tried so far:

- I have installed and logged into Steam,
- Added Fable as a 'Non-Steam-game'
- Opened up workshop and subscribed to a mod,
- then opened the game.

But nothing happened, i.e, No mod was installed when I ran the game.

Obviously Steam isn't picking up the copy of Fable 3 from the 'Non-steam-game' shortcut. How do I tell Steam that I own a copy of Fable 3? Do I need to enter the game's product key into Steam to enable it installing the mods for me?

Comment: Fable 3 doesn't have Steam Workshop... So your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly it is you're trying to do?  Is your example actually what you're trying?

Comment: Hi, and Welcome to Arqade! I think I've managed to clear up your question (please edit it if not!), but I have to agree with TZHX, Fable 3 doesn't have a Steam Workshop entry :(. Is this the actual game you are trying to add, or is it a different game?

Comment: (It would seem that this question is actually about piracy...)

Comment: @TZHX It seems to have been before the edit, yeah. But [per meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/when-does-a-question-support-piracy-and-pirated-games), if the question can be rewritten to ask the same fundamental question without dealing with pirated content, the question is to be left open. (I have a slightly dissenting opinion, but consensus rules.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, but as it stands the question makes no sense, Fable 3 doesn't have mods on Steam Workshop. In fact, I can't find a game that uses the Workshop and isn't a "Powered by Steamworks" game at retail. Does such a game exist?

Comment: @TZHX Hmm, I don't think there is such a game. That's a point in this particular case. Then it should probably be voted closed as unclear, because it's impossible to rewrite it in a sensible matter, or as off-topic-piracy because editing it to be sensible must re-add the piracy aspect.

Answer (score 4):

No. Steam doesn't know anything about the folder structure of non-Steam games, so Steam doesn't know how to install mods for them. Even though Steam sells the same game, it will never recognise that a non-Steam game you add is the same game.

If you want to have Workshop install <strike>Skyrim</strike> *cough* "Fable 3" mods for you, you'll have to actually get the Steam version of the game, either by buying it, receiving it as a gift, or redeeming a Steam Key.

Comment: In some cases you can contact the creator of the game with your proof of purchase, and they will provide you with a Steam Key

Comment: @Robotnik Does that edit cover all the possibilities now?

Comment: AFAIK, yes thank you. It was more the point that someone doesn't necessarily need to purchase the game twice, which is useful info.

Comment: Its entirely possible most of these modifications for **Fable 3** are published by the authors in other ways.  Steamworks is something recently done and is simply a mechanic for Steam to handle the modifications instead of downloading them and maintaining them by hand.  There is also then an added level of validation the files are not malicious.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, the OP knows Skyrim mods can be downloaded and installed by hand. They just don't want to.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - I missed that statement by the author of the question. I agree with your answer. **If you want Steam to manage it give Valve money to do so.**  The only physical games I that Steam can fully integrate are physical Valve games which don't really exist anymore.  There might be a few exceptions of course "Fable 3" isn't one of those.